# Does Chrome Frame work in the legacy IE browser ActiveX control?

Tags: google-chrome-frame

We have a legacy VB6 app that makes use of the IE browser ActiveX control (Shdocvw.dll).  Will Chrome Frame work correctly when a web page is requested via the ActiveX control as opposed to a full stand-alone IE instance?

Thanks